# Unable to perform GSuite Service Account Directory API call without known user

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I've created a service account in G-Suite and delegated it domain wide authorization so that I can collect information on all the Drives within the suite.

The problem I've come across is that I need a list of all the users within the domain.  To do so I can call the Directory API, but the problem is that I actually need to do that as one of the admins.  The problem is that I can't know who the admins are without using one of the admins(or users? I confirmed the call to the directory API with a superadmin account).  Is there a way to call the Directory API without a user email?  Or is there a way to as the service account to get a list of the admins so that I can make API calls on their behalf?

Comment: What language are you writing this in? Can you provide the code you used to successfully list the users using the service account and the superadmin account?

Answer (score 0):

To use Directory API, you must** impersonate one of the admins of the domain, as you say. There really isn't any way around it (as far as I'm aware) - you must ask the admin who's installing your app to provide their email address.

** For some activities, like listing all users, you can impersonate an end user, but that doesn't solve your problem.